# How to Filter by a JSON Key Value Where the Key is Nested at Various Depths?

Tags: javascript, json, karate, jsonpath, graalvm

I have a large JSON response where I only need to update certain fields.  Want to filter down the response, but the key/value pair I'm interested in is nested at varying levels.  I tried to use the jsonpath `..` notation to find it.

```
* eval var testcaseArray = response.collection.item.filter(o => o..name.includes(/^(RD-T|RES-T)/));
```

But the second ellipses is not recognized as valid Javascript syntax.

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:59 Expected ident but found .
var testcaseArray = response.collection.item.filter(o => o..name.includes(/^(RD-T|RES-T)/))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JSON "update" operations will require you to explicitly know the keys and the hierarchy. The JsonPath things such as `*` and `..` won't work.

You could try a brute-force regex based find-and-replace on the JSON and then re-convert it to JSON, but I would not recommend that.

I think it will be possible to recurse all JSON key-value pairs and do this, let me see if I can figure this out and update here later.